# How can I warm up a bathroom without a heater?

Tags: temperature, bathroom

I used to be cold in the bathroom when taking a shower, even in every season.

The curious thing is that I don't feel cold when taking showers at gyms, because those bathrooms and showers have been used before, so they are "warmer" than a simple bathroom.

When I write "warmer" between quotation marks, it means that I have tried to use fan heaters or tools like that, but I'm still cold when I get out from the shower.

Does anyone have a better lifehack?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yea - I have a bath instead, unless the weather's hot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a heater, you're not going to be able to really warm up the bathroom.
But there are a few hacks to mitigate your problem:

1. Use a shower curtain to close off the shower stall. Keep this closed as much as possible. The warm water from the shower generally contains enough energy to warm up the shower stall, but not enough to warm up the whole bathroom. 
   When you finish your shower, keep the curtain closed and dry off inside the shower stall.
2. If you have a shower head that can be detached and aimed at the walls: at the end of your shower, aim the shower head at the walls and run hot water over the walls. This warms them up.
3. Dry off quickly. A wet skin cools off much quicker than a dry skin.
4. Have a bathrobe (or your clothes) nearby but protected from the water, to minimize the time you spend naked.

Comment: To add to your answer, I get dressed in the shower. Placing your clothes near the shower, but away from the water helps this process.

Comment: Keeping the air humid stops the water on your skin evaporating... And its thr evaporation that makes your body feel thr cold

Comment: @Bendy how could keep the air humid ? :)

Comment: Personally I close the door, turn off the extractor fan and have the shower on hot before I jump in to get the steam up

Comment: Make sure the bathroom windows and door stay tightly shut, to retain whatever heat/humidity you have. Also, if you have a clothes dryer, put your clothes and towel in it on high heat for a few minutes. Then, as others have said, dry off and dress in the shower. Warm clothes help during the transition to cooler air.

Comment: You could also (5) take a cold shower, then your body will get used to the temperature in the shower and you won't notice the difference when you get out.

Answer (score 2):

Use heat lamps. You can buy some that screw into normal fixtures. Alternatively, use old school incandescent bulbs. They are capable of baking cakes.

https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/54310/SATCO-S4751.html?utm_source=SmartFeedPriceGrabber&utm_medium=Shopping&utm_term=SATCOS4751&utm_content=LightBulbsIncandescentInfraredHeatLampsBR38andPAR38InfraredHeatLamps&utm_campaign=SmartFeedPriceGrabber&thissku=SATCO777dash777S4751&site=pricegrabber.com